# How to "unfinalize" a graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

It is a good practice to `finalize()` a graph before entering the iterative optimization process, in particular to spot bugs that add operations during the optimization, resulting in avoidable out-of-memory errors.

However, when a graph is finalized, it is hard to inspect or debug the code interactively, because the only handles one has are the ones that are already defined -- and you better have saved them in a python variable or given them a nice name, because browsing all the operations of a large graph with default names can be a pain.

So is there a better way, and in particular can a graph be "unfinalized"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A graph can indeed be unfinalized using the protected method [`_unsafe_unfinalize()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.8.0/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L3098), e.g.

```
tf.get_current_graph()._unsafe_unfinalize()
```

As the documentation (and the name) of this method says,

> Unfinalizing a graph could have negative impact on performance,
>       especially in a multi-threaded environment.  Unfinalizing a graph
>       when it is in use by a Session may lead to undefined behavior. Ensure
>       that all sessions using a graph are closed before calling this method.

Despite this alarming warning, I find `_unsafe_finalize()` useful, especially in the situation of a training going wrong and that is going to be killed anyway.